# Will giving permissions and ownership to the administrator group also give permission to administrators on a different computer?

Tags: windows-10

Say I set a file to have full control permission and ownership for the Administrators, if I transfer this to another computer with a different device name, will the file also have full control and ownership for administrators on that computer? If not, will changing the device name to the same as the original computer, make this the case? I ask because the administrator group has the device name before it, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9IUh.png).

Comment: Permissions are per machine unless you are using an AD domain account which you are not.  Files on an external drive, unless you have changed the permissions by default can already be accessed globally on any machine by any account

Comment: If using non-AD accounts, the file would inherit whatever permissions are set for the directory it's copied to on the other PC

Comment: What about in the case you reinstall Windows on a hard drive already containing files? Since the file is already there, it is not copied. I find that I usually have problems with my programs unless I take ownership or obtain permissions (unsure which fixes it) for the files.

Comment: You will still have to take ownership and give access to the account if the default permissions were changed